# Получить html элементы с определенным атрибутом c помощью htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, атрибуты, htmlagilitypack

Есть html документ с множеством ссылок на картинки следуюшего вида:

```
<a href="picture.jpg" attribute="value">
```

Есть ли возможность получить список всех элементов  с аттрибутом "attribute" с помощью htmlagilitypack?

Answer (score 1):

В htmlagilitypack можно использовать XPath-запросы:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@attribute]");
```